# Background Tint

Tags: android, imageview

How can i use background tint for `ImageButton` or `AppCompatImageButton`? Please answer for both XML and Java.
I have find a java solution that says i most use `setBackgroundTintList()`, but when i use it, the background always shown blue and don`t change on click.
This is what i have tried:

```
mButtonBold.setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{EMPTY_STATE_SET, PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET},
            new int[]{Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN}
))
```

Comment: what are these constants `{EMPTY_STATE_SET, PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET}` ?

Comment: These constants have been defined in android `View` class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First your order of array is wrong. default value must be the last state so use this one:

```
mButtonBold.setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET,EMPTY_STATE_SET},
            new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE}
))
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
    app:backgroundTint="@drawable/background"
    app:backgroundTintMode="src_over"/>
```

**drawable/background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

**JAVA**

if considering the layout is something like this:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
```

then:

```
 AppCompatImageButton imageButton = (AppCompatImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                        new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE}
    ));
    imageButton.setSupportBackgroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

if you are going to use SDK Widget use `android` prefix instead of `app` where

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: Thanks very much!
The java solution works but xml not.
But there is a problem in java solution. In this solution the images background set to green just until button is pressed. I want it remains green until next press, and if user press the button again, change color to blue. How can i implement it?

Comment: My solution answer your posted question, this is another one. Anyway on click button change it manually. you do not need those stuff. use boolean value and check it when the button click

Comment: `setSupportBackgroundTintList()` is restricted to support library group and should be considered private. You want to use `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList()` instead

Answer (score 1):

Changing Tint in **JAVA** Code :

```
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0)); // RED Tint
```

Changing Tint in **XML** Code :

```
android:tint="@color/red"
```

Comment: `setColorFilter()` and `android:tint` change image color by creating a filter on it. but i want to change image`s background color. 
note that my drawable is transparent and i want to change it`s background, not `ImageButton` background

Answer (score 0):

To set the background tint of a button :

i have a tip with xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffff0000"/> 
<!-- pressed --> 
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000ff"/> 
<!-- focused --> 
<item android:color="#ff000000"/> 
<!-- default --> 
</selector>
```

Then set the background to button with:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourbackgroundbutton);
```

Comment: Its creates `InflateException`. I think `android:color` is not available. i have seen an example that use `android:drawable` instead. But i dont want to use a drawable, i want to use simple color.

Answer (score 0):

```
final  AppCompatImageButton imageButton = (AppCompatImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected},
                        new int[]{}
                },
                new int[]{Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE}
        ));
        imageButton.setSupportBackgroundTintMode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageButton.setSelected(!imageButton.isSelected());
            }
        });
```

this will toggle its state if you want like this, when selected it will be green and unselected will be blue.